# Elements positioned over HTML5 video are invisible on iOS in battery saver mode

Tags: html, css, ios, html5-video

We are positioning some text over a  HTML5 `<video>` which acts as a looping video background. However, the absolutely positioned elements are not visible on iOS' Safari, if the battery saver mode is active, regardless of any `z-index` settings. Example:

```html
<div class="example">
  <video playsinline muted loop autoplay>
    <source type="…" src="…" title="…">
  </video>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.example {
    position: relative;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2em;
    top: 2em;
    right: 2em;
}
```

This HTML and CSS code works fine, the text is overlayed over the video playing in the background. However, once the battery saver mode on an iOS device is activated, the text is not visible anymore - and cannot be made visible via a `z-index` either.

Is this somehow by design, so that the iOS user always has the opportunity to actually play the video (i.e. nothing obstructs it), since it will not automatically play in battery saver mode? Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? The video not playing automatically is fine (since that's what is supposed to happen in battery saver mode) - however we would want the text to be displayed.

Comment: Don't know what ios does, but as workaround: Just remove the video if it is suspended. (display: none or something like this). Then the text should be visible.

Comment: The poster image (or first frame of the video) should still be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the behaviour you are seeing is intended to allow the user the ability to play the video if they want in low power mode, as you suggest. It is possibly a use case that was not considered - i.e. to allow for something that is intended to be visible over the video so you could raise a bug request to check this.

In the meantime, as a workaround you can check if your video has been suspended and then make whatever changes you want yourself. See example listener below:

```js
        yourVideo = document.getElementById('your_video_id');
        yourVideo.addEventListener('suspend', () => {
            // Add code here as required
            // e.g. hide the video and display
            // an image and your text instead.
        });
```

Suspend event info is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/suspend_event